# What is the file name for the <> file?

Tags: perl

Sorry for the confusing title, but stackoverflow won't let me use <>...
OK, here is the question:
Since <> can apply to STDIN or the filenames in the commandline argument, what is the file handle in this case if I want to call seek() on this file? Thanks.

### Syntax error:

```
syntax error at ./parsejobs.pl line 17, near ") {"
syntax error at ./parsejobs.pl line 40, near "}"
```

### Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($fh, $curr_job, %jobs, @roots);

@ARGV == 1 or die "usage";
my ($qfn) = @ARGV;
open($fh, '<', $qfn)

while ( <$fh> ) {                                                     <----line 17
  next unless my ($op, $id) = /(\w+): ([.\w-]+)/;
  my $pos = tell();
  if ($op eq 'insert_job') {
    push @roots, $curr_job if $curr_job;
    $curr_job = $id;
    $jobs{$id} = [] unless $jobs{$id};
  }
  elsif ($op eq 'box_name') {
    push @{ $jobs{$id} }, $curr_job;
    peek:    while ( <$fh> ) {
        next peek unless my ($po, $cmd) = /(\w+): ([.\s\w-]+)/;
        if ($po eq 'command' ) {
                push @{ $jobs{$curr_job} }, "$cmd";
                last peek;
        }
        last peek if /^$/;
    }
    if ( $pos != tell() ) {
            seek $fh, $pos, 0;
    }
    $curr_job = undef;
  }
}                                                           <------line 40
push @roots, $curr_job if $curr_job;

display_tree($_) for @roots;

sub display_tree {
  my ($root, $indent) = (@_, 0);
  printf "%s%s\n", ' ' x 4 x $indent, $root;
  display_tree($_, $indent + 1) for @{ $jobs{$root} };
}
close($fh);
```

Comment: `<>` is called the diamond operator

Comment: If you want to call `seek()` on a filehandle, you had better use specific filehandle instead of `<>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file currently being read from by an empty `<>` is called `ARGV`.

Note that there is some magic behavior surrounding `<>`: when you reach the end of the file currently being accessed, perl will automatically open and start reading the next file in `@ARGV`, if there's anything there. (At which point you will *not* be able to `seek` back to your previous location, since `ARGV` now refers to a different file!)

Comment: You also can't seek back if `ARGV` is coming from `STDIN`.

Answer (score 1):

`<>` reads from `ARGV`. I just tested, and you can seek within the currently open file (assuming it's currently reading from a file).

This is a rather odd thing you're doing (and potentially an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)). You might be better off looping over `@ARGV` and opening the files yourself instead of using `<>`.

Comment: For this particular case, it will read from one file. thanks for the information.

Comment: Then why are you using `ARGV`?!?!

Comment: By using ARGV, I don't have to hardcode file name, and it can accommodate STDIN as well...

Comment: You just said it would always be one file. STDIN is rarely a file.

Comment: `@ARGV == 1 or die "usage"; my ($qfn) = @ARGV; open(my $fh, '<:raw', $qfn)` (I assumed you want a binary file handle since you're using `seek`. Get rid of `:raw` if it's text.)

Comment: using <>, the script can read from pipe, which is one of the requirements... but to be honest, I'm just being lazy :)

Comment: You can't `seek` a pipe!

Comment: Or I should say STDIN, it worked. that all I'm concerned with

Comment: Only if it's redirected to a file. `script.pl` or `cat file | script.pl` won't work, for example. So we're back to where we started: Using `ARGV` allows the use of STDIN, which means you encourage behaviour your program can't handle for the misfeature of allowing `script.pl < file` as well as `script.pl file`. Normally I encourage the use of `ARGV`, but your program just can't handle it.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I followed your suggestion to use explicit file handle. Now I got syntax error. hope you can help. I posted above.

Comment: BTW, the file is a text file

Comment: It suggested a mismatch of curly brace, but I checked and all each curly brace has a close brace....

Comment: Missing semicolon after `open`. Probably want `or die $!;`